# What is Salem and PNS in Chase Paymentech?

Tags: in-app-purchase

I have gone through the document given by the site and I also have code snippets but I am confused about the Salem and PNS.

Answer (score 7):

`PNS` stands for `Payment Network Services`, a generic term for all of their merchant payment offerings, and `Salem` is the Stratus platform originally located in Salem, Massachusetts.

The `Salem` platform is optimized for a small number of merchants which have high-volume transactions, such as `Amazon`, `Apple`, `eBay`, and `Google`.  Traditionally, it only had dedicated [ATM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_Transfer_Mode) connections to these "high value" merchants.  Nowadays, I believe it is accessible through `NetConnect` and `Orbital`.

The other platform is internally referenced as `Tampa` and is the one which the vast majority of merchants interact with when using the `Orbital Gateway`.  It uses `Tandem` machines to process higher volumes of merchants submitting relatively small numbers of requests each.

Perhaps thinking of it this way will help.  `Salem` is marketed for companies which have very high volume of transactions (think millions / day), but are few in number.  `Tampa` is marketed for "the rest".